# Gradle sync error when importing moblie ads sdk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-play-services, build.gradle

Hello i am pretty new to android and and android studio .i build some test apps and some apps. when i try importing the mobile ads sdk for admob as in this video [(Link to mobile ads garage video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLLLRUPICcc) it gives me an error

[Image of error in messages view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLuoI.png)

When i click on the **Install repository and Sync project** option in messages view my cursor turns into pointer and android studio stucks.after some time it gets normal and dont install anything.

I enabled google admob by checking the admob option inside **File>Project Structure>Ads**

Here is my build.gradle file of app module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bilalep.swiftbrowser"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Hope it helps to under stand my problem.

Comment: Never use a plus to compile a library. Use an actual version number. And just read the documentation, which is more correct than any video. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Finally got my problem solved. Installing play services from **Android Studio SDK Manager** was not successful eventhough it shown up as installed. I installed google play services,google repository,suppot repository from standalone sdk manager and copied downloaded files to my /AppData/Android/Sdk folder from /Program Files/Android/Android-sdk/extras/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'

Use the above line instead of compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'